# Building new project gives error rbenv: version `2.7.6' is not installed

Tags: ruby, react-native, homebrew, rbenv, npx

on building my new react native project with react native 0.70 using npx react-native init command it gives error while installing bundler that

**rbenv: version `2.7.6'**

is not installed (set by /Users/rahul/Documents/projects/reactNativeProjects/project1/.ruby-version)
current ruby version 2.7.5p203 on ruby -v
rbenv version:  1.2.0-48-g6717c62 on rbenv -v

on running **rbenv install 2.7.6**
it shows like this[image]

Comment: The last 10 lines of the log file don't say particularly much about *why* the `make` commands fails. Could you share some more of the log file contents? In particular parts that contain a stack trace + surrounding lines if they are present.

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a project . By default it get created at react-native latest version whihch is `0.71` requires a ruby version of `2.7.6` .

You have to install the ruby of that specific version. You can install it by following this [link](https://rvm.io/)

Comment: The main issue comes when I am installing ruby 2.7.6 using "rbenv install 2.7.6" then build fails shows like this

 -> ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

-> BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5 using ruby-build 20221206)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/dj/4ffzq1dd1rs37z6r0c67svkw0000gn/T/ruby-build.20230202105341.2455.ESo5eN
Results logged to /var/folders/dj/4ffzq1dd1rs37z6r0c67svkw0000gn/T/ruby-build.20230202105341.2455.log

Answer (score 1):

The error is fairly self explanatory. I'll assume that Ruby 2.7.6 is not installed. To install the Ruby version run:

```
rbenv install 2.7.6
```

Once installed update the version you're using. Assuming you're in your project folder you can update the local version by changing the `.ruby-version` file. This can be done with a `rbenv` command as well:

```
rbenv local 2.7.6
```

Which will update the `.ruby-version` file for you (assuming that you're in the correct working directory).

Finally validate that the new Ruby version is installed and in use.

```
ruby --version
```

Should print `2.7.6`

Comment: I have done this already but on running rbenv install 2.7.6 the build fails BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5 using ruby-build 20221206)